# How to write two ng-repeat by mixing the values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have 2 json ,

```
$scope.start_date=[{'01/02/2016'},{'05/05/2014'},{'08/02/2015'},{'04/08/2016'}]
$scope.end_date=[{'01/02/2016'},{'05/05/2014'},{'08/02/2015'},{'04/08/2016'}]
```

i have to display first start_date and first end_date , second start_date and second end_date using ng-repeat.Is it possible to display like this using ng-repeat using anguarjs. can anyone please help me

Comment: i think those are not valid object

Comment: so i need to have start_date and end_date in a single object to make it work?

Comment: $scope.start_date=[{'01/02/2016'},{'05/05/2014'},{'08/02/2015'},{'04/08/2016'}]
pass it like this

Comment: I  suggest you to merge  your 2 arrays with a loop and after make an ng-repeat on your output array.

Comment: @01axel01christian , i got the idea you suggested, but my doubt is there a built in way to show using ng-repeat

Comment: you should have something like dates = [{ start: '01/02/2016', end: '01/02/2016'}];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for something like below. There are a few ways to do it. `ng-repeat` exposes `$index` which you can use to display an item in the other array, assuming both arrays have the same number of items.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="date in start_date">Start: {{date}}, End: {{end_date[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

And you should make those arrays:

```
$scope.start_date=['01/02/2016','05/05/2014','08/02/2015','04/08/2016'];
$scope.end_date=['01/02/2016','05/05/2014','08/02/2015','04/08/2016'];
```

Comment: Assuming each start_date has a specifically corresponding end_date, it is probably better stylistically to put a `start` and `end` in one object, and then put them in one array (like in @kiro112's answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can format your dates like

```
dates = [{
    start: "01/01/2016",
    end: "01/30/2016"  
}, {
    start: "02/01/2016",
    end: "02/28/2016"  
}];
```

then you can use them in your `ng-repeat` like

```
<div ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <span>{{date.start}} - {{date.end}}</span></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.dates=[{start_date :'01/02/2016',end_date :'01/02/2016''},{start_date :'05/05/2014', end_date:'05/05/2014'}...]
```

pass the date array like this and use ng-repeat as

```
 <ul><li ng-repeat="date in dates">start date : {{date.start_date}} End date : {{date.end_date}}</li></ul>
```